# help fix iCheckbox to work with jQuery 1.6 (works with 1.4.4)

Tags: jquery-plugins, compatibility, jquery-1.6

I need help getting a jQuery plugin (iCheckbox) to work with jQuery 1.6

I set up an example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/mikkelbreum/HAGMp/

If you load jQuery 1.5.2 instead of 1.4.4 the sliding animation stops working. But the change event still fires and changes the output txt.

If you load jQuery 1.6 The animation is still broken, and the change event also stops firing (or the output txt is not changed at least.

Comment: the main problem is, that I don't see any errors en either FireBug or Safari Console, I guess that's because jQuery is silently muting it, ..Is there a way to make jQuery output errors.. there must be something here that stops execution in jQuery 1.5/1.6 but not 1.4

Comment: I've done some progress, it now works in jQuery 1.5 and halfways in 1.6. In 1.6 the toggle moves back again though.. looking into that. http://jsfiddle.net/mikkelbreum/UkXgp/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got it.

There were two problems with the code one making it incompatible with jQuery 1.5 and 1.6 and one making it incompatible with jQuery 1.6.

The first problem was the use of the

```
backgroundPosition property
```

in the animate calls, they needed to be changed into the

```
backgroundPositionX property
```

for jQuery 1.5 and 1.6

The second problem was the check for whether the checkbox is checked or not.
In jQuery 1.4 and 1.5 this could be done with

```
if ( $(this).attr('checked') == true )
```

but in jQuery 1.6 this does not work, it need to be changed into

```
if ( $(this).is(':checked') )
```

The code found here works for jQuery 1.6: http://jsfiddle.net/mikkelbreum/HAGMp/